# Grouping corresponding Rows based on One column

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an Excel Sheet Dataframe with no fixed number of rows and columns.
eg.

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    1    -
A    -    2
B    3    -
B    -    4
C    5    -
```

I would like to Group Col1 which has the same content. Like the following.

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
A    1    2
B    3    4
C    5    -
```

I am using pandas GroupBy, but not getting what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `groupby`:

```
print(df.replace('-', pd.np.nan).groupby('Col1', as_index=False).first().fillna('-'))
```

Output:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    A    1    2
1    B    3    4
2    C    5    -
```

Comment: This code works. But I don't want to use numpy. Can you suggest something using only pandas.

Comment: @KaustubhShrotri i edited it, remember to accept if it works